# Mouse coordinates to 3D world/projection for point collision

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I read through internet that, the correct way to convert mouse coordinates (or touch points) to 3D world and do a sorta of "pick 3d element" is:

1. Multiply model, view and projection
2. Calculate the inverse matrix
3. Store mouse coordinates in a Vector with a [-1,+1] range
4. Multiply mouse's vector with the matrix
5. Check coordinates as collision-checking (in my case, I check when x and y are between [-1, +1])

It works well when I do translations, scaling and even Z rotations, but on my tests it fails on X and Y rotation (and probably on other 3D distortions). I tried different Inverse and Multiply algorithms, but all gaves me the same result. I'm doing something wrong?

For a more detailed description on what's going on in my code, I'll try to explain here what's going on during the 5 steps:
Initially I had [-1, +1] mouse coordinates and, when I did scaling, I found that normalized mouse coordinates should be divided by the scaling value. For example, if mouse is on (-0.8, 0.3) and matrix has a scaling of 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, the result of mouse vector should be (-1.6, 0.6) with no collide point. With this, I had the idea to use the inverse matrix. After that I tried with X and Y's rotation that, from a 2D point of view, it's the same of scaling: giving PI/2 on X and Y, the model looks like scaled of 0.5. But multiplying the inverted matrix with vector gaves me (-0.4, 0.15) as result, giving me a false positive for every time that I use X/Y rotation.

If you want to look deeper on my problem, be free to [download and try my code](https://mega.nz/#!h8xHwKSA!t3RfNB2kmeVKj6q01h1xWg54eptE7mALLhoJFvZYUvk). It's stripped down to the minimum in order to simplify the reading.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and I am not actually sure where this scaling you are discussing comes from? What I see is a single rotation and nothing more.

In order to properly transform from window-space back to NDC space, however, you need to account for the perspective divide (`w`, which is basically `-z_eye`). Rotation around the z-axis will never change the `z` coordinate; the other two axes will, which causes a change in scale in a perspective projection.

But the most important thing to note here is that window-space `w` is actually equal to `1/clip_w`.

#### This would explain why the scaling you discussed here is inverted:

> For example, if mouse is on (-0.8, 0.3) and matrix has a scaling of 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, the result of mouse vector should be (-1.6, 0.6) with no collide point. With this, I had the idea to use the inverse matrix. After that I tried with X and Y's rotation that, from a 2D point of view, it's the same of scaling: giving PI/2 on X and Y, the model looks like scaled of 0.5. But multiplying the inverted matrix with vector gaves me (-0.4, 0.15) as result, giving me a false positive for every time that I use X/Y rotation.

If you properly change the scale to (1/0.5, 1/0.5, 1/0.5) = (2.0, 2.0, 2.0) then the math works.

Comment: I already tried that during the creation of this post:  
vOut.w = 1.0f / vOut.w;  
vOut.x *= vOut.w;  
vOut.y *= vOut.w;  
vOut.z *= vOut.w;  
But this does not resolve the problem of X and Y rotation. Yes, I observed that when vector's Z result is different, the collision test returns false positives, but I don't know how to resolve it even with W handling. Is a raytrace collision check with Z between -1.0 and +1.0 will solve the problem or there is another way?

Comment: @user3040937: Yes, you can absolutely solve this by casting a ray from z= **-1.0** to **1.0** (in NDC space -- this will be **0.0** to **1.0** in most documentation because this is usually done using window-space coordinates). But, to be honest, that is not what you are doing here. You need to calculate two positions and shoot a ray that passes through both.

Comment: The uses of a ray it's an idea that came afterwards.    Now I'm trying with the intersection between the two points (mouseX, mouseY, [-1.0,+1.0]) but, again, without success. I'm also debugging graphically the intersection with a function that draws into a specific pixel when the collision occurs.    https://mega.nz/#!BwAgiIKB!YGWolqLTnNjcJFG-u1EYlIgMBrrfTcbzlLbuBV9g110